# intellij IDEA creating a web client from a wsdl not correctly creating namespaces

Tags: namespaces, wsdl, intellij-idea, webclient

When I create a WebClient via wsdl in IntelliJ, it doesn't seem to properly read the namespace tags and instead creates all the classes in a flattened package.

what I've done is this:
Create a new java project.
Enable webservices.
Right click and go to webservices and select create java code from wsdl or wadl.

Then I select my wsdl location and apache axis, version 1.1, and select the output package and leave the rest of the options alone.

It generates the code but as I said all in one flattened package.

However the wsdl looks like this:

```
<wsdl:types>
<xsd:schema targetNamespace="http://company.com/ServiceContracts/2008/08/Imports">
  <xsd:import namespace="http://company.com/ServiceContracts/2008/08" schemaLocation="http://999.999.999.98/company.Qrs.Consumer.Host/service.svc?xsd=xsd0"/>
  <xsd:import namespace="http://company.com/FaultContracts/2008/08" schemaLocation="http://999.999.999.98/company.Qrs.Consumer.Host/service.svc?xsd=xsd3"/>
  <xsd:import namespace="http://www.microsoft.com/practices/EnterpriseLibrary/2007/01/wcf/validation" schemaLocation="http://999.999.999.98/company.Qrs.Consumer.Host/service.svc?xsd=xsd4"/>
  <xsd:import namespace="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/" schemaLocation="http://999.999.999.98/company.Qrs.Consumer.Host/service.svc?xsd=xsd1"/>
  <xsd:import namespace="http://company.com/DataContracts/2008/08" schemaLocation="http://999.999.999.98/company.Qrs.Consumer.Host/service.svc?xsd=xsd2"/>
  <xsd:import namespace="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Validation.Integration.WCF" schemaLocation="http://999.999.999.98/company.Qrs.Consumer.Host/service.svc?xsd=xsd5"/>
</xsd:schema>
</wsdl:types>
```

When I import the same wsdl with Eclipse, it generates the right packages and subdirectories in accordance to the namespaces.

Anyone know how to import a wsdl in intelliJ IDEA such that it generates the namespaces?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like a [known bug that was fixed recently](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-83005). The fix will be available in IDEA **12** (to be released in the end of 2012, but [EAP versions should appear within several weeks from now](http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/IDEADEV/EAP)).